# How can I load the LinkedIn Javascript API library with a script loader?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

The LinkedIn Api suggests you load their javascript library like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: your_api_key_goes_here
</script>
```

I want to know how I can load this using a script loader (eg. RequireJS or LABJS). It seems the library extracts the api key from within the script tags. This seems like a pretty weird way of doing it in my opinion!

I would prefer to load the library using a script loader, but can't seem to find out how to insert the api_key without using the suggested method.

[The official instructions are here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

From: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/general-methods

Async Loading

To avoid encountering race conditions in your page, you can load the framework asynchronously.

If your page uses JQuery, the following code will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true", function success() {
        IN.init({
            onLoad: "myOnloadFunction"
        });
    });
});
```

Otherwise, you need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    IN.init({
        onLoad: "myOnloadFunction"
        // any other parameters you'd normally put beneath the script element would be here
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In the IN.init() section (where it says "any other parameters you'd normally put beneath the script element would go here") so you'd add api_key: your_api_key_goes_here as a parameter to that function call

Comment: After you initialise the api_key, do you still need to run IN.parse()?  As in: 
``$.getScript(me.linkedInScript, function() {
  IN.init({
    api_key: me.linkedInApiKey
  });
  IN.parse();
})``

Comment: As has been mentioned, the links to `/general-methods` are broken now.

Comment: Adding `?async=true` solved it for me. Then call `IN.UI.Authorize().place();`

Answer (score 2):

Check this out

```
 if(typeof IN === 'undefined'){ //if it is already included don't include that
            $.getScript('//platform.linkedin.com/in.js', function(data, textStatus){
                 IN.init({
                    api_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
                    onLoad: function(){
                        alert("Fully Loaded");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @AdamTrachtenberg you need to use the async version of the API: http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true

next you will have to call the `In.init()` upon load of the API JS.
You should do so in the callback function of you script loader.

You may provide your API Key as a param to `In.init()`

Note: that you do **not** need to pass a callback function `onLoad` to `In.init()`
[a post i wrote about the same](http://ujjwalsingh-betterworld.blogspot.in/2013/01/load-linkedin-api-asynchronously.html)